# How to create loop for first value of three?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have to create a loop that will run until a variable is met. The variables are:

```
a=0
b=a+1
c=a+b
```

The loop must run until c is greater than 5. I have used

```
a=0
b=a+1
c=a+b
    while(c<5):
    print(c)
    a+=1
```

However, when ran the code is an infinite 1 loop :( i'm new to programming and have been working on this simple problem for a while, what am I missing? I am using Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code, you never change the b or c variable, because the code saying b is 1 more than a, only runs before the loop, the b and c definition should also be run in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment 'c' in the loop or it will continue endlessly since c will always be < 5.

```
a=0
b=a+1
c=a+b
    while(c<5):
    print(c)
    a+=1
    c+=1
```

What language are you using?

Comment: Hm this seemed to work, however the addition is not correct. I used a print function to print the sum and it increments: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. The sum should be 1, 3, 5 I believe.

Comment: You didn't specify that it had to do that in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

You Have to increment **c** in the loop

```
while(c<5)
{
  print(c);
  c++;
}
```

if you want to work in a **for-loop**:

```
for(;c<5;c++)
{
  print(c);
}
```

Comment: Incrementing c only adds one to its value each time, making c= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 until the loop ends. It isn't following the math for a and b.

Comment: You can add the lines you want to be executed in the loop